# Working with SCNNode and hitTest

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

When a hitTest() returns the node(s) hit, how can you access the node's properties/methods?

I have a SCNNode that I add to my scene and set the name property to "ball1", but when I do a hitTest() I am unable to access the original nodes properties. Why is this?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if touches.first != nil {

        // We use center because that is where the crosshair is
        let hitList = sceneView.hitTest(centerPointOfScreen, options: nil)


        if let hitObject = hitList.first {
            let node = hitObject.node
            print(node.name) // I get an error saying that is property 
            doesn't exist
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Run the fast enumeration on the scene view.

Comment: @ElTomato  At what point? How do I get the node that was hit and all of its original properties?

Comment: @ElTomato What do you mean? Post an answer ffs.